# std::variant constructed from uint32_t prefers to hold int32_t than std::optional<uint32_t> using GCC 8.2.0

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20

I've got the following code:

```
#include <variant>
#include <optional>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using DataType_t = std::variant<
  int32_t,
  std::optional<uint32_t>
>;

constexpr uint32_t DUMMY_DATA = 0;

struct Event
{
  explicit Event(DataType_t data)
  : data_(data)
  {}

  template <class DataType>
  std::optional<DataType> getData() const
  {
    if (auto ptr_data = std::get_if<DataType>(&data_))
    {
      return *ptr_data;
    }
    return std::nullopt;
  }

  DataType_t data_;
};

int main() {
  auto event = Event(DUMMY_DATA);
  auto eventData = event.getData<int32_t>();

  if(!eventData) {
    std::cout << "missing\n";
    return 1;
  }

  return 0;                                        
}
```

The code is pretty simple and straightforward but I've encountered a weird behavior.
When I compile it using gcc 8.2, the return code is 0 and there is no 'missing' message on the output console, which indicates that the variant was constructed using int32_t.

On the other hand, when I compile it using gcc 10.2 it behaves the opposite way.
I'm trying to figure out what has changed in standard which would explain this behavior.

Here is also compiler explorer link: [click](https://godbolt.org/z/cr933K5db)

Comment: "*The code is pretty simple and straightforward*" I contest this. The construction of a `variant<T, U>` from a type that is neither T nor U is not "straightforward". Piecing together what happens requires a deep understanding of not only the constructors of `variant`, but also of `T` and `U`. In cases like this, it's best to be explicit instead of relying on the esoteric particulars of conversion behavior. *Especially* when the given type is convertible to both `T` and `U`.

Comment: See [p0608r3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0608r3.html) which is implemented by gcc-10. The paper gives a similar example in the "Problems to solve" section.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas I mean, that the code I pasted, itself is simple to understand what it serves for, and there is no need to explain it thoroughly. I didn't mean what is going on under the hood, which indeed is not so straightforward, also that was my motivation to raise this question. I copied it directly from the codebase I've been working on. I've already fixed this bug in my code, but I'm curious why it worked using older gcc.

Comment: @bielu000: My point is that the code *isn't* simple to understand. You say that it "worked" before, but I do not know what "worked" should mean in this context. Either answer seems equally valid to me, and that fact is what makes it not straightforward.

Comment: I don't understand why the code you present has to be so complicated. Why can't you have the `variant`, an assignment, and something to verify what's been set?

Comment: @Bathsheba: It's obviously a piece of a larger codebase. That's what an MCVE is for.

Comment: @NicolBolas I think Bathsheba's point is that it's not very minimal, since it could just [do this](https://godbolt.org/z/r4fc4zdre).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's a reduced version:

```cpp
constexpr int f() {
    return std::variant<int32_t, std::optional<uint32_t>>(0U).index();
}
```

For gcc 8.3, `f() == 0` but for gcc 10.2, `f() == 1`. The reasoning here is ultimately that variant initialization is... complicated.

---

Originally, when C++17 shipped, the way that initializing a `variant<T, U>` from an expression `E` worked was basically by way of overload resolution to determine the index. Something like this:

```cpp
constexpr int __index(T) { return 0; }
constexpr int __index(U) { return 1; }

constexpr int which_index == __index(E);
```

In this particular example, `T=int32_t` and `U=optional<uint32_t>`, and `E` is an expression of type `uint32_t`. This overload resolution would give us `0`: the conversion from `uint32_t` to `int32_t` is *better* than the conversion from `uint32_t` to `optional<uint32_t>` (former is standard, latter is user-defined). You can verify this:

```cpp
constexpr int __index(int32_t) { return 0; }
constexpr int __index(std::optional<uint32_t>) { return 1; }
static_assert(__index(0U) == 0);
```

---

But this rule has some surprising results. This was summarized in [P0608](https://wg21.link/p0608), which included this example:

```cpp
variant<string, bool> x = "abc";  // holds bool
```

This is because the conversion to `bool` is still a standard conversion, while the conversion to `string` was user-defined. Which is... very unlikely to be what the user intended.

So the new rule ended up being (since modified further by way of [P1957](https://wg21.link/p1957)) that before we do the round of overload resolution to determine the index, we first prune the list of types to those that aren't narrowing conversions. That is, those types `Ti` from the pack for which:

```cpp
Ti x[] = {E};
```

is a valid expression. That is *not* valid anymore for `bool x[] = {"abc"};`, which is why the `variant<string, bool>` example now holds a `string` as desired.

But for the original example here, `int32_t x[] = {u};` (for `u` being an `uint32_t`) is not a valid declaration - this is a narrowing conversion (this would work for `0U` directly, but we lose the constant-ness by the time we get to this check).

Once this defect report was applied, we now have this overload set:

```cpp
// constexpr int __index(int32_t) { return 0; } // removed from consideration
constexpr int __index(std::optional<uint32_t>) { return 1; }
static_assert(__index(0U) == 1);
```

Which is why your `variant` now holds an `optional<uint32_t>` rather than an `int32_t`.

---

> The code is pretty simple and straightforward

I hope by now you recognize that attempting to initialize a `variant<T, U>` from a type that is neither `T` nor `U` isn't exactly simple or straightforward.

Comment: Wow, nice explanation!  I learned something new today.  And here I thought the problem was due to `Event(DUMMY_DATA)` having to create a temporary `DataType_t` from a `uint32_t`, and an implicit conversion can't invoke more than 1 conversion at a time, so the temporary can't construct an `optional<uint32_t>`, so it has to use the `int32_t` instead.